# Connect to Google Cloud postgres SQl from Google App Engine Custom flex environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Java application for which the database configuration is read through the following file:

db.properties

```
dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.serverName = 127.0.0.1
dataSource.databaseName = <db name>
dataSource.portNumber = 5432
dataSource.user = postgres
dataSource.password = <password>
maximumPoolSize = 5
```

I have built a Dockerfile which

- creates a container for the java application
- exposes ports 8080, and 5432
- starts the webserver with `ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "jetty:run"]`

My `app.yaml` file for flex environment:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

network:
  instance_tag: nlpapigae
  session_affinity: true
#  forwarded_ports:
#    - 8080
resources:
  cpu: 8
  memory_gb: 40
  disk_size_gb: 32
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 10
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: .75
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <instance name>=tcp:5432
env_variables:
  POSTGRES_HOST: "/cloudsql/<instance name>"
  POSTGRES_DB: <db name>
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <password>
```

When I deploy the application, I get the error that Postgres db is not reachable. How do i get this right?

Answer (score 1):

Try [enabling](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https://console.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.222914331.-1041225607.1547569748) the Cloud SQL Admin API. If you are connecting between multiple projects, check out the [Connecting to App Engine page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#and_in_different_projects) to ensure your service account has the correct permissions.

As a Java user, you may also be interested in the [Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory).

Comment: I have done exactly what you said. I had forgotten to link the documentation in the question. Unfortunately, it hasnt worked out for me. I can't use JDBC Sockets, as I do not want to make any source code changes.

Comment: Can you verify that the default service account for App Engine has the Cloud SQL Connect role and can you post the full stack trace you are seeing?